# how to use different authentication for different functions in a Django rest framework ViewSet

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

how to use different authentication for different functions in a Django rest framework ViewSet?

I have created a UserViewSet, which has 2 functions:

**1. list (list all users registered, permission_classes should be IsAuthenticated)**

**2. register(register a new user, permission_classes should be AllowAny).**

```
--------------------views.py-----------------------------------

class UserViewSet(ViewSet):
    @list_route(methods=['get'], permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, ])
    def list(self, request):
        ...
        ...

    @list_route(methods=['post'], permission_classes = [AllowAny, ])
    def register(self, request):
        ...
        ...


--------------------urls.py-----------------------------------

users_list = views.UserViewSet.as_view({
    'get': 'list',
    'post': 'register'
})

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', users_list, name='users-list'),
    ...
    ...
]


--------------------settings.py---------------------------------

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
}
...
...
```

command line to register a user:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{ "email":"user@example.com"}' http://192.168.30.45:8000/users/
```

Response:

```
{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}
```

the "permission_class" of my "register" function is set to "AllowAny", still needs Authentication? why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to work, I don't really know what's the problem, but you could try writing a customized permission:

```
class IsAuthenticatedOrCreate(permissions.IsAuthenticated):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            return True
        return super(IsAuthenticatedOrCreate, self).\
            has_permission(request, view)
```